# Error when installing packages in Anaconda 3

Tags: python, installation, conda, anaconda3

Recently I have been struggling to install any package using anaconda (BTW I am not an expert to python/anaconda). It has been consistent to unable to install my intended packages (unlike before). The following error report is an example when I tried to install cartopy.

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\logic.py", line 126, in _convert
        return self.names[name]
    KeyError: 'conda-forge/win-64::mysql-connector-python-8.0.27-py37h0612672_0'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1080, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 263, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 275, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 568, in _add_specs
        (_.to_match_spec() for _ in ssc.prefix_data.iter_records()))), self.specs_to_add
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 1109, in get_conflicting_specs
        C = r2.gen_clauses()
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 911, in gen_clauses
        nkey = C.Not(self.to_sat_name(prec))
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\logic.py", line 145, in Not
        return self._eval(self._clauses.Not, (x,), (), polarity, name)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\logic.py", line 131, in _eval
        args = self._convert(args)
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\logic.py", line 121, in _convert
        return type(x)(map(self._convert, x))
      File "C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\logic.py", line 128, in _convert
        raise ValueError("Unregistered SAT variable name: {}".format(name))
    ValueError: Unregistered SAT variable name: conda-forge/win-64::mysql-connector-python-8.0.27-py37h0612672_0

`$ C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install cartopy`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\sm\anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\sm\anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
    GEODA_OGR_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\GeoDa Software
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\sm
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Users\sm\anaconda3;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\U
                          sers\sm\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:
                          \Users\sm\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\sm\anac
                          onda3;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sm\anaconda
                          3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\sm\anacon
                          da3\Scripts;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\condabin;C
                          :\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166\
                          windows\mpi\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Addinsoft\XLSTAT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java
                          \javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\W
                          indows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\NVIDIA NGX;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
                          NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\
                          MATLAB\R2019a\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\W
                          bem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Ope
                          nSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
                          Toolkit;C:\Users\sm\anconda3;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;C:\U
                          sers\sm\Documents;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute
                          2020.3.1;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Use
                          rs\sm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sm\.dotnet\tools;C:
                          \cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;C:\Users\sm\Documents;C:\Users\
                          sm\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\snap\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\sm\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\sm\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\sm\.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.7
         python version : 3.7.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\sm\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/claut/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/claut/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\sm\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\sm\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\sm\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\sm\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\sm\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.7.11 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: Y
Upload successful.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true
```

Anyone who had the same experience? It is just so weird that every single package I install is showing me the same error for the past few days. I am using Spyder (Python 3.7) and Anaconda 3.

Comment: Are you using Spyder or some GUI to install packages, or are you running something from the command line?

Comment: The offending line here is `ValueError: Unregistered SAT variable name` for `conda-forge/win-64::mysql-connector-python-8.0.27-py37h0612672_0`. Surprisingly, there isn't much mention of this error online, so it's pretty rare. Perhaps something like a previously interrupted installation. Can you try removing or reinstalling mysql-connector-python? Seems like the package installation has something to do with it.

Comment: Given that no installs are working, I think a complete reinstall of Anaconda is warranted

Comment: I have the same problem with a package (lammps-interface) and trying removing it does not work - as I get the same error over again.

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro What I did was make a new environment. Errors are gone but you have to install the packages you need in the new environment.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9795
I set pip_interop_enabled = false in my .condarc
Now it's taking forever to execute a "conda update -n base conda" (>24hrs)